# error: expected identifier before '=' token

Tags: c++, mingw, librocket

I am trying to compile a library.

```
class ROCKETCORE_API Property
{
public:
enum Unit
{
    UNKNOWN = 1 << 0,

    KEYWORD = 1 << 1,           // generic keyword; fetch as < int >

    STRING = 1 << 2,            // generic string; fetch as < String >

    // Absolute values.
    NUMBER = 1 << 3,            // number unsuffixed; fetch as < float >
    PX = 1 << 4,                // number suffixed by 'px'; fetch as < float >
    COLOUR = 1 << 5,            // colour; fetch as < Colourb >
    ABSOLUTE_UNIT = NUMBER | PX | COLOUR,

    // Relative values.
    EM = 1 << 6,                // number suffixed by 'em'; fetch as < float >
    PERCENT = 1 << 7,           // number suffixed by '%'; fetch as < float >
    RELATIVE_UNIT = EM | PERCENT,

    // Values based on pixels-per-inch.
    IN = 1 << 8,                //<<----LINE 66----- number suffixed by 'in'; fetch as < float >
    CM = 1 << 9,                // number suffixed by 'cm'; fetch as < float >
    MM = 1 << 10,               // number suffixed by 'mm'; fetch as < float >
    PT = 1 << 11,               // number suffixed by 'pt'; fetch as < float >
    PC = 1 << 12,               // number suffixed by 'pc'; fetch as < float >
    PPI_UNIT = IN | CM | MM | PT | PC
};
```

Error output is:

```
Property.h:66:6: error: expected identifier before '=' token
Property.h:66:6: error: expected '}' before '=' token
Property.h:66:6: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
```

And there are other errors which I believe caused by this enum not being defined correctly.

Any idea why this happens?

Using MinGW 4.7.2 with Eclipse.

Comment: That enum compiles fine. How do you use it?

Comment: Should I put the whole file?

Comment: The problem must lie elsewhere. Have you included the correct code file? Could you give us some more info (comments etc) where the error occurs?

Comment: Maybe `IN` in your case is a macro?

Comment: @Tolga, Preferably the shortest complete sample that replicates the error.

Comment: If you put in the whole file, make sure the lines are numbered. Or give us line 66...

Comment: @chris, it looks like it is indeed, no error after changing that line. It conflicts with another library.

Comment: This is being compiled as C *or* C++. Please pick one.

Comment: Try running just the preprocessor so you can see the input for the compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A typical problem in such cases is a conflict with some macro name defined in some header you included. In your case that would be `IN`, which in some implementations (MS?) is used as a macro for designating input parameters in functions.

A good idea would be to give your enum constants a prefix, like `UNIT_UNKNOWN` instead of just `UNKNOWN`. Alternatively, you can do `#undef IN` after including all "system" headers, but this approach can easily end up being very "high maintenance". A better idea would be, again, to avoid using short all-caps identifiers.

Comment: Come on, that's not a proper answer. This should be a comment.

Comment: It was indeed a macro in `windef.h` - 
`#ifndef _NO_W32_PSEUDO_MODIFIERS
#define IN
#define OUT
#ifndef OPTIONAL
#define OPTIONAL
#endif
#endif` - Solution proposals takes the answer tick.

Comment: +1 for the last line: "avoid using short all-caps identifiers". Obvious, but never thought of it before. Thanks!